# Three dots in url segment in rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A way to avoid a dot in the url segment in route is to use:

```
constraints: { id: /.*/ }
```

This works for `/myroute/foo.bar`, but not for something like `/myroute/foo.bar@email.com`, which I need because some users signed up with their emails as their login name.

If anyone could assist, I would appreciate it.

Comment: have you tried to explicity add @ on the regexp? id: `/[a-zA-Z0-9.@]+/`

Comment: maybe i don't understand well your question but if you want a dot in that regex you need to use /*\.*/ because the period has special meaning in a regex no?

Comment: @fotanus yes. the problem is the second .somethign is being interpreted as a format like foo.bar@mail.org its thinking .org is something like .json or .html

Comment: @microspino no I don't think you understand. .* means any character any or more times. I don't want to specificially match a period, I just want periods not to mess up the router

Comment: @treehau5 it don't take the last .something as a format. If you add dot on the constraints, you lose the format in the URL. Show the full route.

Comment: @fotanus rake routes still shows (:.format)